# Problem with restore softdelete record in laravel filament

Tags: laravel, laravel-filament

I have associated category and product and it has `one to many` relation. When I delete category (soft or hard) the associated products is also deleted. So the error is that when I'm using TrashedFilter in filament to filter delete products. The deleted product table is found and when I click edit or click column it show 404 error. Why does this occur?
I also declare withTrashed in model, route is same.

Restore product:

```
http://localhost:8000/admin/product/2/edit
```

Filter deleted record from trashed filter and go to edit this:

```
http://localhost:8000/admin/product/2/edit
```

```php
public function category() {
    return $this->belongsTo(Category::class)->withTrashed();
}
```

Why is this happening?

I want to edit that data when I filter deleted product records with the trashed filter or hide the edit feature when this deleted record.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.